Map Reduce Job Failing with OOM [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster]
I'm providing the comma separated filenames to the FileInputFormat in MapReduce Job. My total  size of the data is 30Gb compressed snappy orc files.
When my map reduce job is starting immediately after 30secs it is failing with the OOM Error

2024-07-31 00:59:02,572 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:270)
at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeValueString(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeValueString(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredTextImpl.synchronizeData(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.dom.CharacterDataImpl.getData(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2775)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2663)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2559)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1340)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRWebAppUtil.initialize(MRWebAppUtil.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1498)

Does Map Reduce Job tries to load complete input data into memory and run or it executes file by file ??
I've tried below parameters but dint help
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=15360
mapreduce.map.memory.mb=10240
mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xms14g -Xmx14g -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -verbose:gc
mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xms9g -Xmx9g -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -verbose:gc
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb=81920
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts=-Xms77g -Xmx77g -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -verbose:gc
I'm using hadoop version: Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.16.1

Do other mapreduce jobs run? The stacktrace says at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource, so seems like it is failing to read the Hadoop config folder XML files. There is no part of the stacktrace that uses ORC / Snappy libraries.

@OneCricketeer, when my load is 10gb it completed but when my load increases it fails with OOM

Resolved after adding command-opts parameter
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb=6144
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts=-Xms3g -Xmx5g
